# Keep/Pass a Linq Query to a variable OOP

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Is it Possible to keep/pass a like query into a variable in OOP Class for example:

```
private somedatatype linqquery
```

As i know declaring var type of variables can be done in a local-scope

so how to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you mean this: `private IEnumerable<MyType> query = from i in myTypes select x;`

Comment: what do you mean be keep/pass a like query? are you going to pass the result into a variable?

Comment: i want to take a externally provided  `linq query results set` into my proposed class for manipulation and keep it as a private attribute

Comment: Then you should go with IEnumerable<T> - this is the typical result of linq query execution, but it depends on the actual query.

Comment: Do you mean the result from a query, or the query itself?

Answer (score 4):

If by "LINQ query" you mean a query against a query provider like LINQ to SQL or the Entity Framework and you plan on using the query to provide additional manipulations later on (adding additional query conditions or altering the result set, for example), then you should use `IQueryable<QueryReturnType>`. Otherwise, use `IEnumerable<QueryReturnType>` as your data type.

Comment: This will only work if the select from the query does not create an anonymous type.

Comment: @sq33G: This is true. While the OP could always use `IQueryable<object>` or `IEnumerable<object>` in such cases (assuming he's running .NET/C# 4+), that's likely not a great solution. Given that he doesn't mention or demonstrate anonymous types, though, I'll assume that's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

As long as it remains an IEnumerable and you don't use a projection method, it remains a linq query. For example:

```
void FirstMethod()
{
    var myQuery = from XType x in y select x.Stuff;
    SecondMethod(myQuery);
}

void SecondMethod(IEnumerable<XType> yourVariable)
{
    // Will run the query on the next line.
    foreach(XType x in yourVariable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `select x.Stuff` modifies the return type of the query from `IQueryable<XType>` to `IQueryable<type of XType.Stuff property>`. If you want to keep it the same, just `select x`.

Comment: True. Unless .Stuff is of XType class too, but yeah, you're right, I overlooked this.